# Problems after nvidia updates were installed

Tags: drivers, nvidia, multiple-monitors

Hello everyone ,

I am very new with Ubuntu
I installed yesterday about 5 nVidia drivers and after that the pc restarted and all I could see was a black screen with an underline on the top.All I want is to use my pc on two monitors , one of them being my TV. I already have a HDMI cable plugged in and the pc detects my TV but it*s just a black screen. Probably because of  the video card uninstalled updates.

So how do I fix this? Should I install all updates again or should I find another ones ?

Comment: Usually best to only install the correct nVidia driver from the Ubuntu repository. If you installed from nVidia or ppa all the versions will conflict. You need to totally purge all nVidia and current xorg file and start over with just one driver. Multiple different drivers create major conflicts.